# SimpleCallback for dragging view is not working, when i try to move top to bottom and bottom to top dragging item with ItemTouchHelper

Tags: kotlin, view, drag, itemtouchhelper

my RecyclerView scrolls not working top to bottom and bottom to top when i try to dragging. You can see the below code

i'm using xml like this

`

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvDraggable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardViewSeatWise" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution:
So the issues was that my layout

If you are using NestedScrollView just remove and instead of using other layouts use ConstraintLayout

Steps:

### Use ConstrainLayout and RecylerView like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvDraggable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_0"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note- you can also try to use:

- viewBinding.recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
- If you are using notifyDataSetChanged() so just replace it by notifyItemMoved() in onMove() method